# Building ICU on Mac using libstdc++

Tags: xcode, macos, llvm, icu

I was trying to Build ICU4.0 on MacOSX10.11 using Deployment traget 10.9 for libstdc++. In xcode5.0.2 default link library used to be libstdc++ so **runConfigureICU** was working fine but in LLVM7.0 Xcode7.2 default C++ standard library is libc++. is there any way I can build ICU for libstdc++. i tried using `**cxxflags="-stdlib=libstdc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libstdc++**"` in **runConfigureICU** but of no use.

Comment: has anyone Built ICU on MacOSX10.11 Xcode 7.2 for libstdc++?

Comment: Please post the actual problem(s) you're running in to.